# Javascript - subdivided nav opens and close the main one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need the country tab to remain, when the sites expends. I think a forEach loop is causing issues and I am not sure how to adress this, any help is greatly appreciated. I have data to display for over 50 countries and once the function works, my "country" tab will be Copy/pasted, I thought of using hard coded ID but its gonna take forever :(

HTML

```
                        <li class="country"><div class="list_container">

                            <button class="country_name">Algeria</button>
                            
                            <ul class="site_list">
                                <div class="site_container">
                                <li class="site"><a href="" class="site_link">Bejaja</a></li>
                                <img src="imgs/Algeria.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div class="site_container">
                                <li class="site"><a href="" class="site_link">Constantine</a></li>
                                <img src="imgs/Algeria.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div class="site_container">
                                <li class="site"><a href="" class="site_link">Jijel</a></li>
                                <img src="imgs/Algeria.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div class="site_container">
                                <li class="site"><a href="" class="site_link">Setif</a></li>
                                <img src="imgs/Algeria.jpg" alt="">
                            </div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </li>
```

JS

````
const country = document.querySelectorAll('.list_container');


// country selection

country.forEach((item) => {
    const btn = item.querySelector('.country_name');
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        country.forEach((site) => {
            if(site !== item) { 
                site.classList.remove('show_sites')
                }
            })
            item.classList.toggle('show_sites')
        })
})

// site selection

const siteGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.site_container');


siteGroup.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item);
    siteBtn = item.querySelector('.site_link');
    console.log(siteBtn)
    siteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        siteGroup.forEach(site => {
            console.log(site)
            if(site !== item) {
                site.classList.remove('display_site')
            }
        })
        item.classList.toggle('display_site')
    })
})```
````

CSS

```
.country_list {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}
.country {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0.5em; 

}

.country_name {
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: rgba(114, 114,114, 0.5);
    padding: 0.3em 1em;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 15px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}
.list_container {
    height: 2em;
    width: 80%;;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.site_list {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50em;
    z-index: 4;
    padding: 0.3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.site_container {
    height: 1.3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.display_site {
    height: 3.5em;
}

.site {
    padding: 0.2em;
}

.show_sites {
    height: 30em;
}
```

Comment: use event from callback function so you will get exactly the element you are click on 
siteBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {}) and  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {})

Comment: I am not sure how that helps if I already have a specific button selected with :


```country.forEach((item) => {
    const btn = item.querySelector('.country_name');```


please pardon my lack of knowledge

Comment: Imagine you have 5 buttons in you HTML with event you can get the current button you click on and so with other stuff with event you get clicked element event. As you were saying you want to add ID's to all, this is better approach ch. pardon me If i misunderstood.